# mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '430804' for key 'pathology.PRIMARY'

Tags: python, mysql, workbench

My code:

```
  def update(self):
            conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="root",database="pathology")
            my_cursor=conn.cursor()       
            my_cursor.execute("update pathology set num=%s,receivedate=%s,patientname=%s,pathologynum=%s,gender=%s,age=%s,inspechospital=%s,casenum=%s,specimenclass=%s,bed=%s,diagnosis=%s,clinicaldiagnose=%s,inspecdoctor=%s,pathologydoctor=%s,sampledate=%s,reportdate=%s",(
                                                                                                self.var_sys_num.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_rec_date.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_patient_name.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_path_num.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_gender.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_age.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_sub_hospital.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_case_num.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_specimen_level.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_bed.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_diagnosis.get(),
                                                                                                str(contents),                                                                         
                                                                                                self.var_submit_doctor.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_simple_date.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_path_doc.get(),
                                                                                                self.var_report_date.get()             
            ))
```

I want "pathology" table in MySQL Workbench to be updated when clicking on the "update" button.

but the error: mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '430804' for key 'pathology.PRIMARY'

Comment: Against which record you are updating this data ? You will have to pass the "id" or primary key information to update query so that it will update the data for that row. Your code sample only shows the data which you are trying to update but there is no information against which id/which row you want it to update.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement seems to be incomplete, it should contain 'where' clause to identify which record you want to update. Without it mysql may try to insert given values to all the rows of the table, which can lead to a primary key conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and update id information which is mentioned in comment:

```
def update(self):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root',
                                   password='root', database='pathology'
                                   )
    my_cursor = conn.cursor()
    my_cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)

    sql_update_query = """update pathology set num=%s, receivedate=%s, patientname=%s, pathologynum=%s, gender=%s, age=%s, inspechospital=%s, casenum=%s, specimenclass=%s, bed=%s, diagnosis=%s, clinicaldiagnose=%s, inspecdoctor=%s, pathologydoctor=%s, sampledate=%s, reportdate=%s where id = %s"""

    data_tuple = (
        self.var_sys_num.get(),
        self.var_rec_date.get(),
        self.var_patient_name.get(),
        self.var_path_num.get(),
        self.var_gender.get(),
        self.var_age.get(),
        self.var_sub_hospital.get(),
        self.var_case_num.get(),
        self.var_specimen_level.get(),
        self.var_bed.get(),
        self.var_diagnosis.get(),
        str(contents),
        self.var_submit_doctor.get(),
        self.var_simple_date.get(),
        self.var_path_doc.get(),
        self.var_report_date.get(),
        # your id/column info against which you want to update
    )

    my_cursor.execute(sql_update_query, data_tuple)
```